# How can I rewrite following url link in nginx?

Tags: rewrite, regex

How can I rewrite following link in nginx?

```
http://www.example.com/filename/key.value/bar.foo
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/filename.php?key=value&bar=foo
```

Notice .php also, please!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with the [`rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) directive using capture
groups, assuming that there are a fixed number of key/value pairs. Dealing with
an arbitrary number of key/value pairs would probably require the [Lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) module.

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)\.([^/.]+)$ /$1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5
```

Comment: Yes it is going to be an arbitrary number of key/value pairs. How about if you don't have to separate the key.value? You know take that as one variable.  I can do the slit in the script.